# why transaction management using annotation is failing in spring with the below configuration

Tags: spring, transactions

Why transaction management is failing in spring with the following configuration. The transaction is not rolled back even though a RuntimeException is thrown. Well, i am manually throwing it for learning purposes.

My Dao class:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=ArithmeticException.class)
public class TransactionAnnotationDaoImpl extends  JdbcDaoSupport implements JdbcDao {

public void create(Student student) {


try {
    String sql = "insert into student values (?,?,?)";
    getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,student.getAge(), student.getName(), student.getId());
    String marksSql="insert into marks values (?,?,?)";
        int i=2/0; //added to depict roll back behaviour of the transaction when exception occurs
                          getJdbcTemplate().update(marksSql,student.getId(),student.getSubject(),student.getMarks());

            System.out.println("transaction committed");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            System.out.println("transaction rolled back");
        }
    }

}
```

My spring configuration file contents:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db;create=true"></property>
</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="annotationTransactionDaoImpl" class="org.sujay.springjdbc.dao.TransactionAnnotationDaoImpl">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property></bean>
```

I am making call to dao from main method with the following call:

```
 JdbcDao annotationDao = context.getBean("annotationTransactionDaoImpl", JdbcDao.class);
 annotationDao.create(new Student(25, "p", 4, 19, "cn2"));
```

But the transaction is not rolled back. There is an entry in the student table but marks table doesnt have which means transaction is failing. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you catched the exception.

Remove the try catch or rethrow the exception:

```
try{
     ...
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("transaction rolled back");

        throw e; //rethrow so spring will recognize it
}
```

Comment: Bingo..Thanks so much for the help Ralph!